# how to to create a mulitline macro in julia?

Tags: macros, julia, metaprogramming

```
macro Estruct(name,arg,type,max=100,min=0,descritpion="")
        :(struct $(esc(name))
        $((esc(arg)))
        $(esc(name))($(esc(arg)))=new(
          check($(esc(type)),$(esc(arg)),$(esc(name)),$(esc(max)),$(esc(min)),$(esc(descritpion))))
       end)
end
```

how can I imeplent this macro like this:

```
@Estruct begin
    B 
    arg1 
    Float64 
    200.0 
    5.0 
    "this"
end
```

I don't know how to make a multiline macro. I thought I just have to add begin and end, but I'm always getting:  `MethodError: no method matching var"@Estruct"(::LineNumberNode, ::Module, ::Expr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as a multiline macro, that's just a macro that takes a block as an argument. You can see how the macro gets invoked by writing a dummy version of it that just returns its arguments:

```
macro Estruct(args...); args; end
```

Now you can invoke that the way you want to call it and it will return its arguments as a tuple:

```
julia> args = @Estruct begin
           B
           arg1
           Float64
           200.0
           5.0
           "this"
       end
(quote
    #= REPL[12]:2 =#
    B
    #= REPL[12]:3 =#
    arg1
    #= REPL[12]:4 =#
    Float64
    #= REPL[12]:5 =#
    200.0
    #= REPL[12]:6 =#
    5.0
    #= REPL[12]:7 =#
    "this"
end,)


julia> typeof(args)
Tuple{Expr}

julia> dump(args[1])
Expr
  head: Symbol block
  args: Array{Any}((12,))
    1: LineNumberNode
      line: Int64 2
      file: Symbol REPL[12]
    2: Symbol B
    3: LineNumberNode
      line: Int64 3
      file: Symbol REPL[12]
    4: Symbol arg1
    5: LineNumberNode
      line: Int64 4
      file: Symbol REPL[12]
    ...
    8: Float64 200.0
    9: LineNumberNode
      line: Int64 6
      file: Symbol REPL[12]
    10: Float64 5.0
    11: LineNumberNode
      line: Int64 7
      file: Symbol REPL[12]
    12: String "this"

julia> args[1].args
12-element Vector{Any}:
    :(#= REPL[12]:2 =#)
    :B
    :(#= REPL[12]:3 =#)
    :arg1
    :(#= REPL[12]:4 =#)
    :Float64
    :(#= REPL[12]:5 =#)
 200.0
    :(#= REPL[12]:6 =#)
   5.0
    :(#= REPL[12]:7 =#)
    "this"
```

This tells you that the macro gets called with a single argument which is an `Expr` with head type `:block`, i.e. the one argument is a quoted block. To implement your "multiline macro" you need to implement the macro body to accept a quoted block expression and process it, presumably by looking at its `.args` field which is where all the expressions you're interested in are. You'll probably want to ignore all the `LineNumberNode` objects in there and just process the other items in the block.